# Get Embed Video ID from Within Rumble.com HTML

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

Trying to extract the Video ID from this page:
https://rumble.com/vb5dyh-space-x-we-have-lift-off.html

Specifically, the wildcard value is in the source code on that page as follows:

```
Rumble("play", {"rel":1,"resize":"auto16:9","opts":["skip_ga_load"],"video":"v8j7rt","div":"videoPlayer"});
```

The value I'm trying to pull in this example is: **v8j7rt**

This ID is needed for the embed code.

Example PHP code that I'm experimenting with:

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'https://rumble.com/vb5dyh-space-x-we-have-lift-off.html';
$html = file_get_contents( $url );
$dom  = new DOMDocument();
$pattern='"video":"(.*?)"';
// $pattern='\"video\":\"(.*?)\"';
preg_match($pattern,$dom,$match);

print_r($match);
```

Can't seem to extract this value. Is this the right approach? If so, what am I doing wrong with the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to use `DOMDocument()` to parse the raw data!

You had an issue with your regex, see below:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://rumble.com/vb5dyh-space-x-we-have-lift-off.html';
$html = file_get_contents( $url );
preg_match('/"video\":\"(.*?)"/',$html,$match);

print_r($match);

// Array
// (
//  [0] => "video":"v8j7rt"
//  [1] => v8j7rt
// )
```